# Epidemic friendly time traveller

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution, time-travel, viruses

My time traveller from the distant future is about to get stranded back in time, but realises that by travelling back a short time, maybe 100000 years, he is going to leave a trail of destruction by introducing a swathe of advanced diseases among the local populations.

He figures that all he has to do is travel back further: to a point where the proteins and receptors his viruses need haven't been evolved yet. However, he still wants to be able to interact with the inhabitants, so he wants to travel back as little as possible in the hopes of having someone/something sapient to talk to.

How far does he go?

Comment: 100000 years ago he isn't going to find anyone to talk to that he could actually understand, and they'd probably kill him on sight anyway. But in any case they would be hunter gatherers in small groups, he's nopt going to start a huge epidemic. People just didn't travel that much outside their group. Not safe.

Comment: I'm purely interested in the epidemic side here. We could handwave that (a la Dr. Who) with technology. Not interested in how possible it is to learn a language or defend yourself from primatives.
The story I had in mind has someone from the deep future getting stranded in a low tech past. He has automatic medical systems to keep himself alive for hundreds of years and a personal weapon, he's not getting killed. He probably installs himself as a leader of a trading nation with an administrative language made by mixing his language (that he teaches his nobles) with the native language.

Comment: The traveller would get bored really fast if everyone he encountered died within a week.

Comment: Then you need to be within the last 10000 years, before agriculture is no use to him

Comment: The comment says "someone from the deep future"

Comment: oh I get you now...well since we have no idea what the medical tech is like, I suggest he wear a full body condom

Comment: They probably want a less embarrassing solution

Comment: Well, something similar to a space suit but not as bulky, they must have the tech for that. It's a better solution than trying to pick a time, because then the time doesn't matter

Comment: "Handwave that (a la Dr. Who)" and science-based are not compatible.

Comment: Also, lots of viruses will be wandering around in the past that have not made it to the traveler's day. So he wants the full-body-condom for himself. From his point of view, small pox has been extinct for centuries, just as an example.

Comment: @puppetsock Hand wave the language barrier etc. so this question doesn't have to address learning languages, combating the natives, inventing sandwiches etc. This question already involves a time machine, the question is about immune systems.

Comment: @Kilisi, something like [a biohazard suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazmat_suit)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Human viruses in certain cases can infect animals (transmission from animals to humans are the ways the novel coronavirus and HIV epidemics emerged) and even amoebas. So if you want your time traveller not to infect anybody with his own parasites, he should travel to the times before unicont cells emerged (I do not know human viruses that infect plants).

Yet, there is still high probability that besides human viruses he also would carry bacteria and viruses infecting bacteria. Many bacteria can survive on their own without a host.

Comment: I acknowledge Zoonosis is a risk, but it is rare enough to be unlikely to happen to a given individual?

Comment: @pjp This depends on what risk your traveler is willing to accept. This is not a rare occurrence and viruses are very prone to mutations. What prevents the transmission between species is mostly their immune systems rather than incompatibility of the viruses with the hosts. It is possible to conceive that prehistoric animals could have weaker or totally different immune system, incapable of combatting the modern diseases.

Comment: @pjp it is also possible, the traveler would be unsafe contacting the prehistoric animals.

Comment: Well that sucks for him.

Comment: @pjp The only way to make your traveler totally safe biologically-wise, is to completely sterilyze his body of any species other than human. But this would render him quite sick because certain bacteria living in the guts are needed for food consumption.

Comment: Intuitively I'm feel there must be a point at which two species drift so far apart that their microbiomes are no longer compatible at all aside from rare transfer events. Are two creatures isolated and distantly related to each other now a mutual risk?

Comment: @pjp bacterias living in the gut go out each time the traveller poops and many of them can continue to live in the soil. It is unpredictable what consequences this can bring if some animals will eat them. It can go unnoticed or it may make the animal sick. Anyway, it introduces new species to the prehistoric world which weren't there before.

Answer (score 3):

> a point where the proteins and receptors his viruses need haven't been evolved yet

Without any specific information on the receptor the virus is using, the safest bet is, dealing with a virus infecting homo sapiens, to travel to a moment in time when homo sapiens is not yet present on the planet.

> so he wants to travel back as little as possible in the hopes of having someone/something sapient to talk to.

Well, if homo sapiens is not yet evolved, there are no sapiens around to interact with.

Another good reason to follow the recommendation to stay inside and not move from home, neither in space nor in time!

Comment: `Well, if homo sapiens is not yet evolved, there are no sapiens around to interact with.` Given that `sapiens` in the context is a misnomer, the same apply after homo sapiens evolved

Comment: I used sapient, not sapien, meaning "having wisdom". The homo sapien-sapien-sapien-etc. traveler from n-million years in the future doesn't want to have to go back to the permian era to play cards with turtles.

Comment: @pjp yes, I know what sapiens means. I'm just having difficulty to recognize any wisdom in the homo species, no matter how obstinate the repetition of sapiens. As for 'sapient', the etymology is the same, it's a matter of a minor nuance (sapient - being/acting wise, sapiens - possessing wisdom)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, to quote Calvin&Hobbes, the proof that there is intelligent life in the universe is that nobody ever contacted us

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi It was kind of a reply to the answer as well since it's really missing the point of the question: It's not insisting that the traveller or the locals are modern homo sapiens and seems to infer sapient = homo sapiens, despite as you note, the poor correlation. There's also no instant at which creatures stop being one species and become another, mutually immune from each others diseases, its a gradual process. I'm interested in what the time-frame for this would be.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica thx. I'd call it "wise life" instead, based on a distinction I see between wisdom and intelligence.

Comment: @pjp Oh, sincere apologies. Would have been wise for me to stop at being a bit puzzled instead of continuing into an irrelevant rant. Oh well, some never learn.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to sidestep the whole issue of time and wear a coverall suit with helmet, like a spacesuit.

The time wouldn't be a problem then and he could expose individuals to himself on a more clinical level and see if they get sick and die, rather than expose multiple people at once to his dreadful diseases.

Comment: So the time traveler is going to imprison people in quarantine and observe how they react when he infects them? The whole point of an epidemic is that it *spreads*, so if you infect anyone, you had better isolate them or risk infecting everyone else.

Comment: @NuclearWang yep, but not 'when' he infects them... 'if' he infects them

Comment: If you're infecting people by accident, then you clearly do not have the ability to create an effective quarantine (you can't even prevent transmission from yourself to others, much less between others). A prerequisite of a quarantine is knowing who is infected - if you're isolating only the people who are obviously sick, it's too late.

Comment: where did I say by accident? He'd do it on purpose in terms of an experiment, until he opens his suit/helmet there is no danger of infecting anyone. Obviously he'd sort out a quarantine first

Comment: I read "if he infects them" as an unplanned incident. I don't understand, is the time traveler going to deliberately infect others or not?

Comment: @NuclearWang yep he is. In a controlled environment of some sort. Wouldn't be difficult. I said 'if' because there is no guarantee that he's actually a dangerous spreadable disease carrier.

Comment: ... so it's a "when", not an "if".

Comment: @NuclearWang sorry mate, if you cannot understand I can't help you anymore.

Comment: So dark...
I like the idea of the traveller creating an immune group of humans and then weaponizing his own viruses.

Comment: @pjp you guys don't seem to understand that it is not inevitable that people will be infected. I'm from the Pacific where whole populations were wiped out by disease. However it usually wasn't from first contact with Europeans. Quite often contact and trade went along fine for generations until someone sick passed on their malady. Hundreds or thousands of Europeans had been there but not infected anyone, some had even stayed in the Islands and had families and lived out their lives without causing any problems. Same thing in South America.